# After creating a Jupyter service in Iguazio, I'm getting an error that mlrun is not installed

Tags: python, nuclio, mlrun

I created a Jupyter service in the Iguazio UI, opened it, and tried to run one of the pre-loaded demos. I'm getting an error saying that mlrun is not installed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the correct version of MLRun for your cluster, run the `align_mlrun.sh`  script in your home directory in the Jupyter service. This will ensure that the server and client versions of MLRun are aligned

Answer (score 0):

You can install mlrun manually from terminal:

- **on-line installation** (**last version**)

  `pip install mlrun`
- **on-line installation** (**specific version** e.g. 1.2.0)

  `pip install mlrun==1.2.0`
- **on-line installation with proxy** (**specific version** e.g. 1.2.0)

  `pip install --proxy http://proxy-repo.prod:3128 mlrun==1.2.0`
- **off-line installation** (**from source** /v3io/bigdata/mlrun_dist/)

  `pip install --no-index --find-links /v3io/bigdata/mlrun_dist/ mlrun`